# Tar incremental backup restore with one command

Tags: backup, tar, restore

I am trying to restore incremental backups, but to do so I have to extract each archive in a sequence:

```
tar cvf archive.1.tar -g archive.snar backup
```

Making changes in backup folder

```
tar cvf archive.2.tar -g archive.snar backup
```

Making changes

```
tar cvf archive.3.tar -g archive.snar backup
```

When I do

```
tar --list --incremental --verbose --verbose --file archive.3.tar
```

I can see the list of files from the current snapshot.
but I need to run:

```
tar xvf archive.1.tar -g /dev/null -C destination
tar xvf archive.2.tar -g /dev/null -C destination
tar xvf archive.3.tar -g /dev/null -C destination
```

in sequence to get the last backup.
Is there a way to do this with one command?

```
tar {some options} archive.3.tar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat archive.*tar |tar xvf - -g /dev/null --ignore-zeros -C destination`

At the end of tar files, is the 'end-of-archive' marker (2x 512 blocks of zero bytes. Tar will continue to read past the marker in some cases, but will not take any data.

`--ignore-zeroes` will tell it to keep reading regardless.

Related: Tar supports appending to archives; it does this by seeking to the end, rewinding two blocks, then continuing to write.

Comment: Please do not use gtar's incrementals. Gtar is able to do incremental backups but it cannot do incremental restores for non-trivial changes between two incrementals. The related bugs have been reported in 2004, 2011, 2016 and 2018 to no avail.